# NullPointerException em um servlet ao usar método de DataVoting

Tags: java, servlet, nullpointerexception

Estou trabalhando com um *servlet* porém, esta dando erro `java.lang.NullPointerException` quando uso o método do objeto `DataVoting`. Segue o código:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    DataVoting dataVoting;
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    request.getSession().invalidate();
    dataVoting = new DataVoting();
    if(request.getSession() == null){
        request.getSession(true);
    } else {
        dataVoting = (DataVoting)request.getSession().getAttribute("DataVoting");
    }
    request.getSession().setAttribute("DataVoting", dataVoting);
    Gson gson = new Gson();   
    String discipline = request.getParameter("discipline");
    if(discipline != null) {
        switch(discipline) {
            case "Desenvolvimento de Sistema Web3": 
                if(dataVoting != null) {
                    dataVoting.Vote(1);
                }
                break;
            case "Sistema Operacional":
                dataVoting.Vote(2);
                break;
            case "Engenharia de Software":
                dataVoting.Vote(3);
                break;
            case "Inglês Aplicado":
                dataVoting.Vote(4);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Nenhum case!");
                break;

        }
    }
    request.getSession().setAttribute("DataVoting", dataVoting);
    String json = gson.toJson(dataVoting);
    response.getWriter().print(json);
}
```

Comment: Onde acontece o erro?

Comment: Em dataVoting.Vote(1);

Comment: É impossível dar esse erro neste local, ele só tenta executar este método se não for `null`.

Comment: Por isso mesmo, ontem mostrei ao professor, dei até um system out dentro do case e funcionou o system out. Mesmo deixando tudo comentando a IDE apontar o mesmo erro. Professor também não conseguiu ver razão para o erro.

Comment: Código precisa ser bem feito para funcionar sempre. Quando funciona em certas situações e em outras não, o código precisa ser reescrito. Vou tentar responder mas não sei se vai te ajudar já que a informação passada não bate.

Comment: Obrigado, eu só queria mesmo entender esse erro, porque nunca vi desse jeito. Mas como disse é consegue mostrar o retorno de um método no system out, mas não consegue fazer uma operação que envolva a alteração de um atributo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É difícil afirmar com certeza com tão pouca informação e desencontrada. Você diz que o código está mal feito só para ver se funciona. O problema está aí, faça ele bem feito e vai funcionar. Todo o código deveria ser escrito de outra forma.

Neste caso específico em 3 `case`s acessa o objeto `dataVoting` que pode ser nulo sem verificar.

Se a informação passada for minimamente verdadeira, claramente há uma situação em que este objeto fica nulo e neste caso o problema é mais sério e todo este método está comprometido. Ou arruma uma forma de obter o valor ou ele deve abortar a execução. Não pode tentar executar em estado inválido.

Pode até não ser este o problema, mas este é um potencial problema visível. Outros problemas não visíveis só com o que foi postado podem existir.

Códigos precisam ser escritos pensando em todas situações possíveis. Eles precisam ser testados em todas circunstâncias que podem ocorrer. E testar quando uma informação é inexistente é básico. Este código parece fazer coisas demais também.

Fica difícil ajudar em código que faz pouco sentido. Mesmo que resolva o erro dele, você terá que mudar o código, aí outros erros podem ser introduzidos. Deixe o código o melhor que der. Se ele estiver bom, não terá erros, mas se tiver, pelo menos será em cima de algo que faz sentido, algo que não é hipotético.

Aprenda executar o código no *debugger*. Vai executando passo a passo, vendo todos os valores, vai aprender muita coisa e descobrir onde e como resolver o erro.

Comment: Ok, obrigado irei refazer o código ^^!

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos, conseguir descobrir o problema. Foi relacionado a IDE toda vez que eu mandava compila ela não conseguia criava uma nova *build*, por isso que mesmo quando eu simplesmente colocava o código comentado ela ainda alegava erro no comentário. Mesmo limpando não funcionava. Ai criei outra classe, copiei meu código do `get()` e coloque nessa nova classe, apaguei a *build* anterior na mão e encerrei o processo da IDE e do servidor. Com isso deu para analisar melhor o código sem aquele erro estranho. E Maniero enxuguei o código. Ficou assim no momento, vou melhorar ainda:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();   
    DataVoting dataVoting;
    dataVoting = new DataVoting();
    if(request.getSession() == null){
        request.getSession(true);
    } else {
        if(request.getSession().getAttribute("DataVoting") != null) {;
            dataVoting = gson.fromJson((String)request.getSession().getAttribute("DataVoting"), DataVoting.class);
        }
    }
    String discipline = request.getParameter("discipline");
    dataVoting.Vote(discipline);
    String json = gson.toJson(dataVoting);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("DataVoting", json);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

Comment: O código ficou bem melhor. Não sei se faz tudo o que você espera mas não dá para melhorar muito mais que isto. A única coisa que talvez esteja exagerada é muita declaração de variável quando vai usar o dado apenas uma vez, ou declaração separada da atribuição.